# Linux/Nohup/Qt: starting an external Qt program from a system command with nohup (inside a non-Qt daemon) does not work

Tags: c++, qt, embedded-linux, daemon, nohup

Inside an USB daemon named **tep2020gateway** I've got a function **swUPdating** (that is updating my application: **tep2020ihm**) by using the generic tool **swupdate**.

Inside that updater daemon **tep2020gateway** :

- First I stop the application **tep2020ihm**
- Then I try to start a small Qt application named **update_ihm** to display a progress bar while I'm updating the app.
- Eventually I launch **swupdate** to do the updating

PROBLEM: the progress bar supplied by **update_ihm** never appears, the screen does not change, as if the update_ihm app was not started (or stopped immediately despite the **nohup**)

If I type the command **(nohup /usr/bin/update_ihm </dev/null)&** in a console, that works: the progress bar shows up. Everything works fine. But it does not work from the system command.

Here is my (short) function, I hope it's readable enough:

```
static void swUpdating(void) {

    syslog(LOG_INFO, "Stopping tep2020ihm and starting update_ihm");
    int rc = std::system("bash -c 'systemctl stop tep2020ihm; echo >nohup.out; (nohup /usr/bin/update_ihm </dev/null)&'");

    syslog(LOG_INFO, "%s %d : Starting Sw_update (stop tep2020ihm/start update_ihm returned rc=%d)", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, rc);
    rc = std::system("bash -c '" SW_UPDATE " -k " PUBLIC_KEY " -K " AES_KEY " -i " DATA_FILE " >" LOG_FILE " 2>&1'");
    syslog(LOG_INFO, "%s %d : Sw_update starting returned code: %d", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, rc);

    <...>

    unlink(DATA_FILE);
}
```

You can see there are syslogs in the function, I can see them in the logs:

```
May 24 07:51:26 Tep2020-220 local1.info /usr/bin/tep2020gateway[187]: Stopping tep2020ihm and starting update_ihm
May 24 07:51:26 Tep2020-220 local1.notice /opt/pfd2020/tep2020ihm[207]: received signal #15
May 24 07:51:26 Tep2020-220 local1.notice /usr/bin/tep2020gateway[187]: received signal #17
May 24 07:51:26 Tep2020-220 local1.info /usr/bin/tep2020gateway[187]: void swUpdating() 72 : Starting Sw_update (stop tep2020ihm/start update_ihm returned rc=0)
May 24 07:51:26 Tep2020-220 user.debug swupdate: RUN [extract_sw_description] : Found file:     filename sw-description         size 596       checksum 0x88ce VERIFIED
May 24 07:51:26 Tep2020-220 user.debug swupdate: RUN [extract_sw_description] : Found file:     filename sw-description.sig     size 256       checksum 0x7604 VERIFIED
May 24 07:51:26 Tep2020-220 user.debug swupdate: RUN [swupdate_verify_file] : Verify signed image: Read 596 bytes
```

EDIT: this was fixed by adding the platform to the command.
When I turned this small bargraph **update_ihm** into a service I got the message "Missing Qt plugin", i.e. the platform was missing. This was fixed my adding it:
**update_ihm --platform linuxfb:fb=/dev/fb0**

Comment: Is `update_ihm` a graphical application, or do you mean a progress bar on the console? Graphical applications launched from system daemons usually don't work, because `DISPLAY` is not set (and there might not even be an X server). Progress bars shown on the console are usually suppressed if stdout is not a tty, because they don't work when redirected to a file.

Comment: Yes it's a graphical Qt application supposed to display the update progress on the screen of the device. Trying to follow that clue now. Thanks.

Comment: It might work to just set `DISPLAY=:0.0` in the daemon's environment. Not a very flexible or robust solution though.

Comment: In fact we're working with Qt Framebuffer on a small embedded device. The platform was missing ("missing Qt plugin" I got when I tried to make a service of this small bargraph...). I could fix it by adding a platform: update_ihm --platform linuxfb:fb=/dev/fb0 . Thank for your hint that led me to the conclusion.

Comment: please post answers as answers not as part of the question

Comment: Ok. Done. I made a separate answer with the fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: this was fixed by adding the platform to the command.

When I turned this small bargraph **update_ihm** into a service I got an error message in the logs of the servie:"Missing Qt plugin" (i.e. the platform was missing).

This was fixed when I added it: **update_ihm --platform linuxfb:fb=/dev/fb0**